# Difference between fla , swf and as files

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash, fla

I am new in Flex 4 and ActionScript 3 So while reading, I found these file extensions many times. As I know that Application developers use MXML in combination with ActionScript to develop rich Internet applications, with products such as Adobe Flex. But I am unable to understand that what are these files and actionscript file is `.as` file.
But when somewhere I found these extensions `swf` and `fla` then it make me confuse.
Are `.as` , `.fla` , `.swf` are same files? if no , then what are the difference among these?
As I mentioned that I am very much new to Flex and ActionScript then I hope experts will tolerate if this quesion is bogus or not good

Answer (score 7):

It's easy: `.as` is a textual file , contains ActionScript 3 code , you can write it even in NotePad. `.fla` is format of Adobe Flash IDE , it contains graphics and animations and some code too. You can compile both `.as` and `.fla` into `.swf` file - Adobe Flash Player can open and play/show it. Every browser has Flash Player plugin inside it , so you can see all the flash games and banners . Clear?

Comment: It means that if I am using flex builder then ActionScipt files would be stored with .`as`  extension as it is readable by flex builder and if I am using Adobe Flash IDE then it will store same action script file with `.fla`?

Comment: @Despicable In Flash IDE you usually create graphics , and in FlashBuilder you write your code. Flash IDE is worst for code writing.

Comment: @Despicable yes , at the end both of them know to compile to `.swf` . You can make graphical stuff in Flash , compile it to `swf` , after that you can `embed` this `swf` in FlashBuilder and continue work on it